# Pull down a pull request from an origin

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

So I'm very possibly doing this completely wrong. Here is the situation:

- ProLoser has flexbox.less up on github, a public repo
- I contributed to this by forking it to my own account, setting it as the upstream origin, creating my own branch, making changes, and then doing a pull request through the Git UI online
- ProLoser accepted the pull request

So I have a few questions here:

1. This seems like a pain in the ass, is there an easier way to do this?
2. I ran git fetch upstream, then git merge upstream/master to get my local copy to mirror what is the current origin's master branch (right?)
3. Now I want to make new changes--what I've done so far is to do git branch qacheck to create a new branch, then git checkout qacheck; from there, I made a few changes, and then ran git push --set-upstream origin qacheck so that my changes would be up again (in my fork not the original)
4. I assume, once i'm done, **I go ahead and do the pull request through the UI again?**

**Second question**--There is another pull request from another person, I need to check it for formatting and validity/completeness before ProLoser accepts the pull request. How do I get that pull request down to my local so I can check it, change it, push it back up and get it approved?

Gah, I felt like I knew a lot about Git until I got into the whole fork thing...

Comment: *Git UI online* do you mean GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I meant github.com pull request functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described sounds like the typical github workflow. (except for step 3)

The reason for the pull request is to provide the original author a chance to perform a code review. If the upstream admin trusts you, they *could* give you push rights to that repo and you could skip the whole code review process (not recommended).

Keep in mind that you can append multiple commits in 1 pull request. If I understand what you are describing in step 3, then you shouldn't need to create a new branch for each pull request.

Lastly, I don't see why you would be responsible for checking someone else's commits for formatting & validity. That should be the upstream admin's role.

Comment: Sounds like if I'm going to be doing some validity checking it would be easier if I was just accessing the original project.